# Retrieving single property value in Gremlin query closure works, but retrieving valueMap() fails yields Exception

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

Using the Titan 1.0.0 Gremlin shell I can retrieve a single property value from an edge from within a closure. But trying to access the `valueMap()` fails with an exception.

Works:

```
gremlin> t.E().hasLabel("TRUSTS").has('NOT_VALID_BEFORE').each( { trustEdge -> t.E().has('EDGE_GROUP_ID', trustEdge.value('EDGE_GROUP_ID')).hasNot('NOT_VALID_BEFORE').each({println it.value('EDGE_ID')}) } )
```

Yields exception (only difference is in the right most closure 'it.valueMap()' vs 'it.value('..')'):

```
gremlin> t.E().hasLabel("TRUSTS").has('NOT_VALID_BEFORE').each( { trustEdge -> t.E().has('EDGE_GROUP_ID', trustEdge.value('EDGE_GROUP_ID')).hasNot('NOT_VALID_BEFORE').each( { println it.valueMap() } ) } )
No signature of method: com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.relations.StandardEdge.valueMap() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: value(java.lang.String)
Display stack trace? [yN]
gremlin>
```

But it is not that in general I would be unable to get to the valueMap of the edge:

```
gremlin> t.E().hasLabel("TRUSTS").has('NOT_VALID_BEFORE').each( { trustEdge -> t.E().has('EDGE_GROUP_ID', trustEdge.value('EDGE_GROUP_ID')).hasNot('NOT_VALID_BEFORE').each( { println it } ) } )
e[215rmh-oe094-1d05-9i0][40964296-MANAGED->12312]
gremlin> t.E('215rmh-oe094-1d05-9i0').valueMap()
==>[MANAGE_INFORM:false, NOT_VALID_AFTER:1669873006000, MANAGE_MANAGERS:false, MANAGE_AUTHENTICATION_MEANS:true, CREATED_AT:1487683094863, RELATIONSHIP_ROLE:FAMILY_DOCTOR, MANAGE_TRUST:true, UPDATED_AT:1487683094915, MANAGE_REPRESENTATION:false, EDGE_ID:122881049, VERIFIED:true, EDGE_GROUP_ID:122881049]
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

A little context, just in case the query does not even do what I think it does: 
What I think I am doing here is looking up all edges with label "TRUSTS" that have a property NOT_VALID_BEFORE. For each of those edges I look up all edges that share the same edge group ID value and check if they also have a property NOT_VALID_BEFORE, printing those to the console that do not have the property set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start iterating with `each()`, every item you manipulate inside the closure is "off the traversal" -- that is, you're working with an `Edge` object, not an `GraphTraversal` object.

[`Edge`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.0.1-incubating/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Edge.html) has a `value()` method similar to the `GraphTraversal`, but it does not have a `valueMap()` method. You could use [`ElementHelper.propertyValueMap()`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.0.1-incubating/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/util/ElementHelper.html#propertyValueMap-org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element-java.lang.String...-) instead.

Here's a quick example:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.E().valueMap()
==>[weight:0.5]
==>[weight:1.0]
==>[weight:0.4]
==>[weight:1.0]
==>[weight:0.4]
==>[weight:0.2]
gremlin> g.E().each{ edge -> println ElementHelper.propertyValueMap(edge) };[]
[weight:0.5]
[weight:1.0]
[weight:0.4]
[weight:1.0]
[weight:0.4]
[weight:0.2]
```